# Dynamic Controls not appearing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm creating dynamic controls and they do not appear when there is a post back.

I'm redrawing the controls when there is a postback, but they do not appear.

By the way, the controls are inside an Update Panel.

This is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.WriteLog("Drawing the menu");
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        drawMenu();
    }
}

private void drawMenu()
{
        if (ViewState["SubjectList"] != null)
        {
            subjList = (ArrayList)ViewState["SubjectList"];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < subjList.Count; i++)
        {
            try
            {
                log.WriteLog("Drawing Item:" + i);
                MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
                item.Text = subjList[i].ToString();
                item.Value = i.ToString();
                NavigationMenu.Items.Add(item);
                log.WriteLog("Item Added : " + subjList[i].ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                log.WriteLog(e.ToString());
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How do you set the `IsPostBack` value? My guess is that it isn't set properly.

Comment: you checked ViewState["SubjectList"] is not null and arraylist has elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the UpdatePanel and is working fine now. I believe it was something related to Updatepanel. Thanks for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving your code to the `LoadViewState` method, not inside `Page_Load` which happens too late in the execution pipeline:

```
protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
{
    log.WriteLog("Drawing the menu");
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        drawMenu();
    }
    base.LoadViewState(savedState);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to redraw the dynamic control at every postback. so no need to check page 
Ispostback. check your viewstate the data become available after postback or not.

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    log.WriteLog("Drawing the menu");
    drawMenu();

}

private void drawMenu()
{
        if (ViewState["SubjectList"] != null)
        {
            subjList = (ArrayList)ViewState["SubjectList"];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < subjList.Count; i++)
        {
                MenuItem item = new MenuItem();
                item.Text = subjList[i].ToString();
                item.Value = i.ToString();
                NavigationMenu.Items.Add(item);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Controls that you create dynamically must be recreated everytime the page loads. The proper place for that is the Page Init event, not Page Load:

If your controls need to retain a value during a postback, they have to be recreated before the ViewState is loaded and applied to the controls - this happens before Page Load and after Page Init.

Please read about and understand the [ASP.NET Page Lifecycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).